# Prove:$\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2}\geq2 $ ,if $-1<x,y<1$

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization

> Prove:
>   $$\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2}\\+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2}\geq2 $$ 
>   if $-1< x,y< 1$.

I tried Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and I proved Left side is greater or equal than 1

I also tried QM-GM inequality but I could not prove it.

Comment: Where is $y$ used ??

Comment: So it's basically same thing 4 times on the left side

Comment: What happens for $x=1$. It's not defined.

Comment: i removed them. The question is in correct form now thanks for your patience, I finally could post a question.

Comment: Cauchy ineuqlity once.

Comment: Just show that each individual term is at least half, this is quite trivial to proof I guess.

Comment: @YohanesAlfredo: Is it really? Unless I am mistaken, each term can be arbitrarily close to $1/8$.

Comment: See the [inequality plot here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%3C%3D1%2F%28%28x-1%29%5E2%2B%28y-1%29%5E2%29+%2B1%2F%28%28x%2B1%29%5E2%2B%28y%2B1%29%5E2%29%2B1%2F%28%28x%2B1%29%5E2%2B%28y-1%29%5E2%29%2B1%2F%28%28x-1%29%5E2%2B%28y%2B1%29%5E2%29)

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that:
$$\left(\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2}\right)+$$
$$+\left(\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2}\right)\geq2$$ or
$$\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+2-2(x+y)}+\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+2+2(x+y)}\right)+$$
$$+\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+2-2(x-y)}+\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+2+2(x-y)}\right)\geq2$$ or
$$\frac{2(x^2+y^2+2)}{(x^2+y^2+2)^2-4(x+y)^2}+\frac{2(x^2+y^2+2)}{(x^2+y^2+2)^2-4(x-y)^2}\geq2$$ or
$$\frac{2(x^2+y^2+2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2+4-8xy}+\frac{2(x^2+y^2+2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2+4+8xy}\geq2$$ or
$$\frac{(x^2+y^2+2)(2(x^2+y^2)^2+8)}{((x^2+y^2)^2+4)^2-64x^2y^2}\geq1$$ or
$$(x^2+y^2)^3(2-x^2-y^2)+4(x^2+y^2)(2-x^2-y^2)+64x^2y^2\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: HOW DID YOU COME UP WITH THE FIRST LINE"SIMPLE COMMON DENOMINATOR"

Comment: @Amos The first line it's your inequality.

Comment: @Amos I added something. See now.

Comment: VERY NICE THANK YOU

Comment: @Amos You are welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101425/discussion-between-amos-and-michael-rozenberg).